# Postgres trigger function, to aggregate rows from another table and insert column into different table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with FKs: pvd, and analyst. I would like to populate two columns in the pvd table using a trigger function that fires off aggregate functions on two columns of the analyst table. While my example stand alone query works fine, my trigger function is not populating the fields I would like it to populate. See syntax below. What I want is to populate the pvd data with COUNT(DISTINCT A.analyst), and the AVG(A.keep_kill) from the these fields in the analyst table.

Any assistance or better ideas or methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

This simple subquery works currently:

```
SELECT P.chip_uid, P.fac_id, COUNT(DISTINCT A.analyst) AS analysts, AVG(A.keep_kill) AS kk_avg
FROM database.pvd P JOIN database.analyst A
     ON P.fac_id = A.fac_id
WHERE P.chip_uid = A.chip_uid and P.fac_id = A.fac_id
GROUP BY P.fac_id, P.chip_uid
```

Which creates a nice results table with four columns.

I m trying to use this query logic to develop a trigger function on the pvd table to automagically go grab the aggregate data for analysts, keep_kill. The trigger function is doing nothing. I do not get any errors or any results.

This is the trigger function I have come up with so far:

```
-- FUNCTION: database.pvd_fields()
-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS database.pvd_fields();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION database.pvd_fields()
     RETURNS trigger
     LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
     COST 100
     VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
     UPDATE database.pvd
          SET analysts_cnt = S.analysts, kk_avg = S.kk_avg
     FROM (
          SELECT P.chip_uid, P.fac_id, COUNT(DISTINCT A.analyst) AS analysts, AVG(A.keep_kill) AS kk_avg
          FROM database.pvd P JOIN database.analyst A
          ON P.fac_id = A.fac_id
          WHERE P.chip_uid = A.chip_uid and P.fac_id = A.fac_id
          GROUP BY P.fac_id, P.chip_uid) S
     WHERE database.pvd.chip_uid = S.chip_uid and database.pvd.fac_id = S.fac_id
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION database.pvd_fields()
     OWNER TO admin;
```

The database table pvd trigger looks like this:

```
-- Trigger: pvd_fields
-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS pvd_fields on database.pvd;

CREATE TRIGGER pvd_fields
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
     ON database.pvd
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE FUNCTION database.pvd();
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: 1) Read [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), then you would know that `RETURN NEW` has no effect in an `AFTER` trigger. 2) Use a `BEFORE` trigger.  Then `DECLARE rec_var record` and then `SELECT P.chip_uid, P.fac_id, COUNT(DISTINCT A.analyst) AS analysts, AVG(A.keep_kill) AS kk_avg INTO rec_var ...  WHERE NEW.chip_uid = S.chip_uid and NEW.fac_id = S.fac_id `. Then `RETURN NEW`. FYI, this `database.pvd.fac_id` is not a good idea. It works here because you are not comparing across databases, other Postgres does not support database references directly.